# How to scroll down in selenium on a drop down menu

Tags: selenium

so i am fairly new to selenium and i am using it to auto fill some attendance form that our school gives, in that form one part is to select the subject and since the list is long the subject i am taking is at the bottom of the list.
[image: the list of subjects]

as you can see the mathematics is at the bottom and since selenium can't scroll down it throws this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

i have already searched for an answer but all i see are questions on how to scroll down webpages and not a drop down menu,
here is my current code:

```
time.sleep(3)
#To select the drop down menu
subject_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")
subject_select.click()


time.sleep(3)
#To select the subject maths
sub2_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[19]/span")
sub2_select.click()
```

https://forms.gle/QcCcDcUAhokCxBH89
here is a carbon copy of the exact page i made for testing purposes

*Even though the class has a drop down menu since my class is at the top i dont have an issue with that*
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's helpful to display the html snippet of the DOM so we can see if this is "traditional" html select box, or more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after a few hours of tweaking around i figured out that when you open the dropbox and you type the first few letters of that subject it auto chooses it and if you don't select it, the form auto selects it.

here is the final code:

```
time.sleep(3)
subject_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")
subject_select.send_keys("Math")
```

cool thing was i didn't need the second part of the code.

Comment: You shouldn;t use sleeps. Also if you post the HTML, this process goes faster.

Comment: yes I know this is my first time posting a question about selenium so I had no idea how to ask sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you may want to improve your XPATH (you can likely look for a element based on the title "mathematics" like this:

```
//*[@id='mG61Hd']//span[contains(.,'Mathematics')]
```

but ultimately you may need to scroll to that element:

```
#To select the subject maths
sub2_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[19]/span")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(sub2_select).perform()
sub2_select.click()
```

Comment: i did this still gives the same error, i imported the ActionChains moduel and it still doesnt scroll down

Comment: is it still "element not interactable"?

Comment: I wonder if you're selecting the wrong element? Can you post the html of th edrop down?

Comment: i have fixed this now, check my answer i posted here